# Math equation validation regex for javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

**I want to have a validation for my Math equations**

Let us assume I have equations as follows:

**1)** x + y = e // valid equation

**2)** x + sin(x) = y //valid equation

**3)** a + wq = c // invalid equation

**4)** sin(x) + s =y //invalid equation // as s is not wanted only x,y,e characters are allowed to type in

**I only want to allow equations which may contain x,y any other special character like e , also the functions like sin,cos,tan,sec,csc,cot,arcsin,asrccos,arctan,arcsec,arccot etc.
But if the equation contains a single letter like the above equation then the equation is not valid.**

So can anybody provide me with a Math Regex that would help me validate?

Thank in advance!!

Comment: debug it further. to broad otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same thing happen to me. The content security policy prevents the ChromeExtension from being able to access the GLOBALS array, which make sense. The  Chrome Extension ideally should be sandboxed, as Chrome Extensions have extended permissions.

That being said this is the wild west AND gmail.js is an unsupported JS library that could change with changes in the Gmail code, so you are already assuming a fair amount of risk by using it.

It is possible to inject the Gmail.js code into the Gmail application and instructions are outlined here

https://github.com/KartikTalwar/gmail-chrome-extension-boilerplate

Use the structure here and you should be able to access the GLOBALS array within GMail.